# Flutter app crashes upon launching app in android

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I've been trying to make an offline app using json for local storage in flutter. I've used a package `path_provider` to get current directory app apk.

I've already asked this question but I got tagged with similar questions and now is not seen publicly. Here's the link of the original question that I've asked :-

[Flutter app crashes after using package path_provider, how do I fix it in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728525/flutter-app-crashes-after-using-package-path-provider-how-do-i-fix-it-in-flutte?noredirect=1#comment112693235_63728525)

The app crashes as it launches.

I've tried out the solutions that are given to this question but the problem persists.
Also I have no experience in java, how do get the solution for this from a flutter developer's perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while creating the Flutter App a pop up asks about the project name and details etc, kindly fill in the 1) package and 2) Select Windows additionally while creating app on windows platform along with  * Android *IOS . 3) If using the linux, select Linux along with *Android * IOS in Android Studio. Note* The above Solutions works with Android Studio.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).